# How do I get user input of dialog box in variables in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, dialog, user-input

I have the code below to assemble a dialog box:

```
prompt = {'Enter matrix size:','Enter colormap name:'};
title = 'Input';
dims = [1 35];
definput = {'20','Green'};
answer = inputdlg(prompt,title,dims,definput)
```

Basically I want to save in variables the inputs of the user
like `n=20` and `color=Green`.
How to do that?

Comment: Have you looked at the variable `answer` after running your code? It should contain a `2x1` cell array with your inputs.

Comment: yes but if i get the values with indexing parenthesis to answer it returns again cell array not a number

Comment: Then index the cell array using [curly braces](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html#d120e33488). It would help tremendously if you included the actual problem you're having in your question. There is no mention in your question of indexing with parentheses.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try:

```
n = str2num(answer{1});
color = answer{2};
```